# Can the Top-Level-Site be recovered or does it need to be re-created?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, server-farm, farm-solution

Yesterday I was working on a project and thought I was within that specific site when I wanted to delete it, but accidently deleted the main site of the Farm. Today I went into SPD and found that there are sub sites of the main site that are still available. Couldn't I just re-create the main site and have the sub sites pointing to the main site? There are no backups. :( BUT I did go through the database yesterday and noticed all of the lists, pages, etc. still reside there! Is this possible or is it more complicated than this?

Comment: Do you mean you deleted the central administration site? You're gonna love this - Service Pack 1 of SP2010 has a site recycle bin, but that's not been released yet :)

Comment: Not the Central Admin site, thank goodness! The main site that has many sub sites, someone told me that was the farm. Yeah, I heard that yesterday, it is going to be released at the end of the month.

Comment: Ah right, I've deleted my post as it was completely wrong. Basically, "The Farm" represents all the servers, all the websites, all the services, all the databases and all the other accoutrements that make up SharePoint. It sounds more correct to say you've lost the "Root Web" of your Site collection. But it could also be that you've accidentally deleted the Web Application, which is just the entries in IIS (the web server) for your site, which is more easily recoverable than a lost Root Web.

Comment: However, if you've deleted the Root Web, there is no easy way out of this, and is the reason why backups are particularly so important in SharePoint. If you have deleted the Web Application from IIS (have a look and see if you can see it in there), I believe this is recoverable.

Comment: look in the IIS? How can I recover this? Hopefully we can recover this and then I will make sure we perform a FULL backup on EVERYTHING!

Comment: When I go into SPD I am able to view other sub sites, however when I chose the Parent of the sub sites (the one that was deleted) I receive an error message: Server error: The URL "http://parent/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll" is not contained within a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to recover anything if you don't have backups... Also, by sub-sites do you really mean other site collections? Could you give an example of some of the URLs? I think there is some confusion over what actually was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you deleted the top-level site collection in your web application. I believe if you delete the top-level site of a site collection, SharePoint automatically deletes the Site Collection. No - without a backup, there is now way to recover site or site collection deletions without a backup of your SQL database OR a backup of the specific site collection.

Comment: What is interesting though is that I have the subsites still. I was advised that the top level site couldnt have been deleted unless the subsites were deleted.

Comment: I was thinking if I need to create (OK please help me out here as many people have given me many different terms for the SAME site, is it a Farm (I thought that was the Central Administration), is it a ROOT Web, or is it a top-level site)? I was calling it portal and someone told me Portal reffers to a subsite. 

I was thinking perhaps if its the site itself I can recreate the site and link the subsites back to it? Wouldn't there have to be data in the database in order for me to still bring up the sub sites?

Comment: Farm is all the servers, web apps, site collections, etc. Central Admin is a web application with a single site collection hosting the administrative site for SharePoint (aka Adminstrative Web). Content web applications (mapped to a virtual website in IIS) can contain a single top-level site collection at the root of the web app, and sub-site collections (e.g. /sites/<blah>. Each site collection has a top-level site, and subsites. Yes, it is bit confusing.

Comment: You should not be able to delete the top-level site in a site collection without deleting the entire site collection (and all sub-sites that were beneath it). Its possible something weird happened when you deleted your site that left the site collection and sub-sites intact, but I doubt it. The top-level site collection of a web application frequently hosts "The Portal", with non-root site collections hosting dept sites, etc. I suspect you deleted the top-level site collection.

Comment: That is what happend. My intentions were to delete a subsite of the top level site. I went to Site Actions-> Site Settings-> Site Actions -> Delete site Template. I have no clue how it was the top level site that was deleted and not the subsites. I am aware that even in a regular HTML page, building websites, you have to delete the folders before deleting the main site of the page. Something like this happened to me in my courses(non-SharePoint), but I was able to locate the home of the links, recreate the link and page. All pages were reconnected baised on the naming convention.Possible here?

Comment: Someone who set up the site asked me why I was in the root site. Wouldn't I have to be to create, delete or make modifications to the subsites? I'm sure this can also be done in SPD, but it seems easier to do this in SharePoint vs SPD-sometimes.

Comment: OK, so if deleting the top-level-site is not supposed to be possible without deleting the subsites, what could have happened for this to occur? Is it possible that SharePoint was not installed properly?

Comment: I know you are frustrated - I am sorry for your loss. I don't think that SharePoint is installed correctly, but without more information I can't know exactly what happened.

Comment: What more information are you looking for? I am more than willing to provide whatever needs to be provided. I did find this site, [General SharePoint Online:Accidentally deleted top level SharePoint site](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/1552/10684.aspx), but am wondering if it would work in my situation, considering I still do have the sub-sites. I can find them in the browser and they return, if not then I will give, but mind you in the spirit of adventure and pushing the envelope, that would not be in my nature (analyst, you know how we are :)).

Comment: So, the only thing that needs to be verified is whether you did in fact delete a top-level site of a site collection somehow without deleting the sub-sites, or whether you deleted a site collection, and are just see sub-site collections. To that end, the following would be useful: a) what are the browser URL's of the site you deleted, and the sub-sites still working, b) a list or screencap of the Managed Paths for the web application hosting the site (you get this from Central Admin > Manage Web Applications > Managed Paths, and c) a list of the site collections on the web application

Comment: A)I do know the URL that was deleted and I have opened all of the sites that I can remember and they are ALL here. I can open them and work within them if I wanted to. B) this brings up Define Managed Paths (nothing selected) C) that is found @ Central Administration -> Site Collections -> View all site collections (and all of them are here)

Comment: Turns out that only the top level site was deleted because I had hit the back button in the browser after seeing the 404 Error and then selected 'Cancel' like crazy because I didn't want the top level to be deleted, which resulted in only the top-level-site being deleted.

Comment: I continue to have a strong suspicion you are confusing sub-sites with sub-site collections. Here goes my last word on this thread: a) if the top-level site you deleted is a seperate site collection, you can just create a new one at the root of your web application - nothing else is required b) if what you say is true, then you will need to create a new site collection, then import/export your old sub-sites to the new site collection, then delete your old site collections, then backup/restore new one to right location. You cannot create a new top-level site in an existing site collection.

Comment: Thank you, what I said was confirmed by a consultant yesterday.